# How to show session variable in my controller's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication, post

I have controller's POST action method  :

```
 def appinfo
    puts session[:arr]

    u = User.find_by(apikey: appliance_params[:apikey], id: appliance_params[:id])
    if u
      render json: session[:arr]
      #session[:arr] = nil
      puts session[:arr]
    else 
      render json:  "UserError : error, i haven't found such user with this params :("
    end
  end
```

but also a wrote this code

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:appinfo]
```

I send POST request to .../appinfo.
And if i want to `puts session[:arr]` in my method `appinfo`, it is give me nothing

How can i get `session[:arr]` ?:

Comment: What session[:arr] should be?

Comment: something like it : `{:ids=>"4", :status=>"1"}
{:ids=>"4", :status=>"0"}`